# What is a "linked" question?

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

If you take a look at this question

[How to scan and detect spying software](https://superuser.com/questions/595601/how-to-scan-and-detect-spying-software)

you can see that on the right column, just above the list of "related" questions, there is another one listed as "linked".

What does it mean? I've already seen that in case of questions marked as duplicate, it points to the relevant duplicate question, but the one I am referencing here doesn't apply, and it also doesn't have any link in the text body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any links found in the question, answers or comments will appear in the Linked list on the sidebar. These are manual, by the users.

Those that appear in the Related list are automatically selected by the system.

Comment: It's also bidirectional, any question that links to this one will also show up.